# Нужно ли ставить тире в случае с именами?

Tags: тире

У меня есть предложения вида:

> Вспоминая школьные годы, автор рассказывает нам о своем учителе литературы - Юрии Викторовиче Подлипчуке - и о его влиянии на учеников

или

> Ираклий Пимениди - таксист - просто не мог оставить людей в беде.

Нужно ли в таком случае обособлять ФИО тире? Нужна ли запятая? Можно ли поставить запятые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Вспоминая школьные годы, автор рассказывает нам о своем учителе литературы — **Юрии Викторовиче Подлипчуке** — и о его влиянии на учеников.*

*Ираклий Пимениди — **таксист** — просто не мог оставить людей в беде.*

1. **Когда мы используем тире,** а не запятые для обособления приложений? Это указано в правилах Розенталя. § 19. Обособленные приложения
   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Пункт 10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире:
3) для выделения (с двух сторон) приложения, носящего характер **пояснения**:
*Достали глубиномер — гирьку на длинной бечёвке — и промерили глубину*; *Смотритель ночлежки — отставной солдат скобелевских времён — шёл следом за хозяином* (Фед.);

2. Итак, если приложение является **уточняющим**, то оно обособляется запятыми, тире же используется, если приложение **пояснительное**. В первом случае имена в большей степени значимы для текста, а во втором это дополнительная информация, не имеющая прямого отношения к повествованию. Поэтому выбор знака зависит от контекста и является авторским решением.
3. Дополнительные запятые **не нужны**, если на месте обособленного приложения не было никаких знаков, в том числе **перед союзом И**.